# JavaScript setInterval does not work with asp net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, animation, intervals

I want the label text run animate when i click to the button, but it's not work. If i use **window.setInterval(afun, 150)** outside the function, the label text will run automatic event i'm not click to the button. Where is my bug ?. Sorry for my bad English.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div runat="server">

        <p id="demo" runat="server">
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="label1">Animate Text</asp:Label>
            <asp:Button OnClientClick=" return afun();" Text="button" runat="server" />
        </p> 
    </div>
</form>

<script>

    function afun() {
        var element = document.getElementById('<%=label1.ClientID%>');
        var eText = element.innerHTML;
        var lengText = eText.length;
        window.setInterval(function () {
            eText = eText[lengText - 1] + eText.substring(0, lengText - 1);
            element.innerHTML = eText;
        },150);
    }
    //window.setInterval(afun, 150);
</script>
```

Comment: see what error you are receiving in developer console in browser ,Press F12 and go to console tab , if you are using chrome

Comment: I checked, it's blank in console.

Comment: Remove runat="server"

Comment: Check HTML output generated in browser dev tools (post output tags if necessary). I tried using standard HTML and your JS function worked properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button is getting generated as a `Submit` button inside the form as following.

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl03" value="button" onclick=" return afun();">
```

You need to return `false` from your javascript to stop the default posting. Or you can also use plain `HTML` button in your code if you don't want your button to post.

Change your `JavaScript` function as following.

```
  function afun() {
        var element = document.getElementById('<%=label1.ClientID%>');
        var eText = element.innerHTML;
        var lengText = eText.length;
        window.setInterval(function () {
            eText = eText[lengText - 1] + eText.substring(0, lengText - 1);
            element.innerHTML = eText;
        }, 150);
        return false; //ADDED THIS LINE TO STOP FORM POSTING
    }
```

Comment: Hey,@PSK. How to make that button run a function in code behind to change "Animate Text" text then run javaScript function to animated it.

Comment: Better go for AJAX call to get the text and then call the JS function to animate